# Devise ignoring permitted parameters on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass an additional parameter for my devise user model on **Rails 4**. Since it needs to be permitted I added a filter to my main application controller as below.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  prepend_before_filter :add_allowed_devise_session_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def add_allowed_devise_session_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit("avatar") }
  end

end
```

But when submitting for :sign_up I am still getting the error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: avatar
```

The parameters look like this:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vp1ir2TJwZXwYGFtDc97bSf/dnXQQl1pksHVxdVTaWc=",    "user"=>{"name"=>"stan@merkwelt5.com", "email"=>"stan@merkwelt5.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa05762a918 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/8y/g14_rdxx31gb35dyjhltk4xc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131219-7366-vf7of8>, @original_filename="instagram_logo.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"instagram_logo.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I validated that the filter is actually called on :sign_up and its per the devise documentation:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I overlooked that the devise controllers had to be updated. Didn't look there since the devise documentation points to ApplicationController.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

   def update_sanitized_params
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:avatar,:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)}
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:avatar,:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)}
   end

end
```